# What size of tyres can I use on my BTwin Original 5?

Tags: road-bike, tire, hybrid-bike, size

I own a hybrid, BTwin Orginal 5 which is almost 5 years old. Lately I've been doing a lot of road cycling.

This bike comes with 700x42c ISO 44-622 size tyres which weigh in around a kg per pop. I wish to change my tyres to help me improve my speed and my cadence as I feel the tyres I have now are weighing me down a lot and I have to put it double the effort other road bike riders have to put in. The bike weighs in around 14kgs.

I would love it if anyone could help me out with what size tyres I can put on this bike as I am pretty confused with mixed response from a lot of people. I would like slimmer tyres which could be used in road conditions. I am confused as I don't know if I can put a proper 28mm or a 25mm road bike tyre on my bike or if I have to stick with the hybrid standards of 32mm or 35mm tyres of which all are 700c. Pls help.

[image]

Comment: Note tire widths are measure in millimeters not inches - edited your question to fix that. TLDR yes you can put narrower tires on, but you are limited by the rim width. 25mm are very likely not possible, 28mm maybe, 32 likely. Note that inflation pressure and tread  will make a big difference also. A 32 or 35mm tire will minimal tread inflated to 80PSI will roll much easier than a treaded 42mm at 40PSI

Comment: You really need to find out the size of your rim. Best by measuring the inside or by reading the specs. I actually think that 25 mm might be possible if they gave you some narrower rim, it used to be common to put narrower rims on the bikes than it is common now. But you need to know the rim size.

Comment: For speed on the tarmac look for a tyre with smooth tread or only with small (in all directions) tread blocks. You do not need to go too small in tyre diameter at all, the tread is more important. Even road racers will use 28 mm now, depending on the event. 25 mm is mostly good if your rim brakes do not allow more - but yours do.